# How do I search in another workbook and add to existing number in that other workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

With current sheet's (and current workbook) values, I want to search in another workbook, find that value and update the stock (adding the numbers together) which belongs to that value.

My code: (Subscript out of range error)

```vb
Sub Upload()

Workbooks.Open "P:\Engineering\Stock Management\EngineerBookingSystem.xlsm"

cProd = Sheet1.Range("D6")
CAdd = Sheet1.Range("F6")

Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("EngineerBookingSystem.xlsm")
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet9")

LastRow = wks.Range(wks.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If wks.Range(wks.Cells(i, 1)) = cProd Then
        'found it
        wks.Range(wks.Cells(i, 3)) = wks.Range(wks.Cells(i, 3)) + CAdd    
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I tried YouTube videos, Stack Overflow Q&A, whatever I try errors.

Comment: Change `Workbooks.Open "P:\Engineering\Stock Management\EngineerBookingSystem.xlsm"` to `Set wkb = Workbooks.Open ("P:\Engineering\Stock Management\EngineerBookingSystem.xlsm")`, for starters.

Comment: Change `wks.Range(wks.Cells(i, 1))` to just `wks.Cells(i, 1)`. Same goes for `wks.Range(wks.Cells(i, 3))`.

Comment: Appreciate these! However, when I've made the appropriate changes it errors before even running...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Upload()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    cProd = ws.Range("D6")
    CAdd = ws.Range("F6")
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("P:\Engineering\Stock Management\EngineerBookingSystem.xlsm")
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet9")
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If wks.Cells(i, 1) = cProd Then
            'found it
            wks.Cells(i, 3) = wks.Cells(i, 3) + CAdd
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```